# C++ Static variable accessible by class member

Tags: c++

Please have a look at the following code:

```
#include<string>
class abc
{
  public:
    static const abc PENDING;
  private:
    static const string PENDING_STATUS_CD;
    abc ( const string& iStatus )
    {
     //...........
     Logintodatabase();
     //.............
     logoutfromdatabase();

    }
};

const string abc::PENDING_STATUS_CD  = "P";
const abc abc::PENDING ( abc::PENDING_STATUS_CD );
```

---

Once the const abc abc::PENDING( abc::PENDING_STATUS_CD ); is called, it will call constructor `abc ( const string& iStatus )`.

In fact if more than one static class variable is defined inside class, for each initialization it will call the constructor.

This constructor is responsible for opening & closing the database.
For each static variable initialization, the database will open & close.
Suppose this class is used by more than one process then so many times database will open & close.

can you suggest how to overcome this issue?

can anyone tell me how to design this logic?

Comment: You ask for a solution but the problem is still a little unclear. Please can you edit the question to elaborate on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The database is a dependency. Pass it from outside, maybe in the constructor. Assume it already is open and let the caller of your class worry about opening, closing or caching connections.

On a technical level, if you don't want to do dependency injection, look up `connection pooling` for your respective database.

Comment: is it true once below line will called it will call constructor?

    const abc abc::PENDING ( abc::PENDING_STATUS_CD );

Comment: can we do any design in such a way that all static variable will become non-static. or is there any impact on my new design?

Comment: You should design it in a way, that the logic of your constructor is somehow injected, so you can have it in another place that can then decide about caching.

Comment: these are static varaible, can we make it non-static or design logic. suppose if i am doing non-static what things need to take care can you please explain clearly?

Comment: It's hard to explain clearly if the expectations are unclear. You should look up `Dependency Injection` and maybe (although I think it's an anti-pattern) `Singleton` patterns in a good book or tutorial.